Output of grey filter is always a black image
I'm reading "Programming Massively Parallel Processors 3rd edition" and I'm trying to implement this example on my own:
// we have 3 channels corresponding to RGB
// The input image is encoded as unsigned characters [0, 255]
__global__
void colorToGreyscaleConversion(unsigned char * Pout, unsigned
char * Pin, int width, int height) {,
    int Col = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int Row = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    if (Col < width && Row < height) {
        // get 1D coordinate for the grayscale image
        int greyOffset = Row*width + Col;
        // one can think of the RGB image having
        // CHANNEL times columns than the grayscale image
        int rgbOffset = greyOffset*CHANNELS;
        unsigned char r = Pin[rgbOffset
        ]; // red value for pixel
        unsigned char g = Pin[rgbOffset + 2]; // green value for pixel
        unsigned char b = Pin[rgbOffset + 3]; // blue value for pixel
        // perform the rescaling and store it
        // We multiply by floating point constants
        Pout[grayOffset] = 0.21f*r + 0.71f*g + 0.07f*b;
    }
}

But on my implementention I always get a black image:
// %%writefile greyscale.cu

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#define THREAD_X_COUNT 32
#define THREAD_Y_COUNT 32
#define CHANNELS 3

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

__global__ void colorToGreyscale(
    unsigned char *input,
    unsigned char *output,
    size_t rows,
    size_t columns)
{
    size_t column = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    size_t row = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.y * blockDim.y;
    if (column < columns && row < rows)
    {
        size_t greyOffset = row * columns + column;
        size_t rgbOffset = greyOffset * CHANNELS;
        float r = float(input[rgbOffset]);
        float g = float(input[rgbOffset + 1]);
        float b = float(input[rgbOffset + 2]);

        output[greyOffset] = static_cast<unsigned char>(0.21f * r + 0.71f * g + 0.07f * b);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Mat input = imread("/content/sample.jpg");
    if (input.empty())
    {
        cerr << "Error: Image not found\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    size_t rows = input.rows;
    size_t columns = input.cols;
    size_t inputSize = rows * columns * (sizeof(unsigned char) * CHANNELS);
    size_t outputSize = rows * columns * sizeof(unsigned char);
    Mat output(rows, columns, CV_8UC1);

    unsigned char *h_input, *d_input, *d_output;

    h_input = (unsigned char *)input.ptr<unsigned char>(0);

    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_input, inputSize);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_output, outputSize);

    cudaMemcpy(d_input, h_input, inputSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 dimGrid(ceil(columns / (float)THREAD_X_COUNT), ceil(rows / (float)THREAD_Y_COUNT), 1);
    dim3 dimBlock(THREAD_X_COUNT, THREAD_Y_COUNT, 1);
    cout << "Grid: " << dimGrid.x << "x" << dimGrid.y << "x" << dimGrid.z << endl;
    cout << "Block: " << dimBlock.x << "x" << dimBlock.y << "x" << dimBlock.z << endl;
    colorToGreyscale<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(d_input, d_output, rows, columns);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    cudaMemcpy(output.ptr<unsigned char>(0), d_output, outputSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    imwrite("cuda_greyscale_sample.jpg", output);

    cudaFree(d_input);
    cudaFree(d_output);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/*
%%shell
nvcc -o greyscale greyscale.cu `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4` && ./greyscale && rm greyscale
*/

Is there any error on the code?
I tried explicitly casting the r, g and b values, plus explicitly casting the grey channel result, but it doesn't work either.

Your assumptions about the size and memory layout of the OpenCV matrices you are loading and storing to is almost certainly wrong. You also have no CUDA error checking of any kind in your code, so if there was a GPU side error, you would not know. Revise both and try again

Hi @talonmies, thank you for your response, I used a macro for error checking and got CUDA error greyscale.cu:62: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version, turns out I didn't enabled the GPU on the Google Colab environment. Now it runs well. Any advice on how to improve my code?

Sorry [SO] is a question and answer site. If you want advice, you probably need to look elsewhere.. And on that front, omitting you were using Google colab was a very important piece of information which you didn't provide.  99% of CUDA related errors running on Colab are due to not selecting a GPU runtime, or exceeding compute time on the free scheme and getting kicked off. Keep that in mind for next time

imread loads images as BGR, not RGB. | If you start at 0 and count by increments of 1, you get 0, 1, 2, not 0, 2, 3 as you seem to think.

I believe that for OpenCV color images, the channels are interleaved by default, so the rgbOffset should be like this: size_t rgbOffset = row * columns + ( CHANNELS * column ); Also, OpenCV image rows are aligned, so you should be using step instead of cols to compute pixel indices as well as for allocating device memory.
